# how to convert vmdk image to hda.qcow2

Tags: window, vmware, vmdk

I am trying to convert vmdk formate image to hda.qcow2 formate through this command:

```
    qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 server\server2016.vmdk hda.qcow2
```

but it show the following error

```
    qemu-img : The term 'qemu-img' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
```

function, script file, or operable program.
  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
   is correct and try again.
  At line:1 char:1
   + qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 server2016.vmdk server2016.qcow2
  + ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (qemu-img:String) [], 
    CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do this two-stage conversion (vmdk->raw->qcow2) in bash using `qemu-img` QEMU utility (in Debian qemu-utils package)

```
echo "Converting multiple VMDK files in $PWD into QCOW2..."

rm -f tmpImage.raw
for i in *.vmdk; do
    echo "Converting $i ..."
    qemu-img convert -f vmdk "$i" -O raw "$i.raw"
    cat "$i".raw >> tmpImage.raw
done
echo "Creating finalImage.qcow2..."
qemu-img convert tmpImage.raw finalImage.qcow2
rm tmpImage.raw
```

The only real question is whether we want to append the unsequenced "$i.vmdk" file to the end of its final raw image before converting, but it seems to work best this way.